# Newer CouchDB/Sofa Tutorial

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

**Is there a newer version of the [Sofa tutorial for CouchDB](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/documents.html#edit)?** I'm trying to follow the examples given in the text, but they are wildly different than the Sofa source code cloned from http://jchrisa.net/drl/_design/sofa.

If not, are any other step-by-step guides or tutorials for CouchDB beginners recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the Kanso docs useful, there are guides covering lots of topics starting from the basics: http://kan.so/docs

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into this. I also found http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-couchapp/section3.html to be helpful, although the loader.js file doesn't seem to work on Mac or Linux. I've posted that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271452 if you've got another minute to take a look.