# couchapp does not generate loader.js

Tags: jquery, couchdb, couchapp

I'm trying to use **couchapp** to manage my CouchDB application, but it's missing a crucial file after generating the project, `loader.js`. It looks like this is an [existing issue](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/issues/103) (for the last  6 months) that hasn't been addressed by the couchapp team.

I first tried to [upgrade the vendor folder](https://github.com/couchapp/vendor), but this didn't work:

```
couchapp vendor update git://github.com/couchapp/vendor.git
2012-02-13 22:57:50 [CRITICAL] vendor `git://github.com/couchapp/vendor.git` doesn't exist

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 48, in dispatch
    return _dispatch(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 92, in _dispatch
    return fun(conf, conf.app_dir, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchapp/commands.py", line 294, in vendor
    vendor_update(conf, dest, vendorname, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchapp/vendors/__init__.py", line 14, in vendor_update
    vendor.update(dest, name, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchapp/vendors/base.py", line 139, in update
    raise VendorError("vendor `%s` doesn't exist" % name)
VendorError: vendor `git://github.com/couchapp/vendor.git` doesn't exist
```

I then tried to simply copy the `loader.js` file into `vendor/couchapp/_attachments`, but this didn't work either.

**Does anyone have a workaround to allow `loader.js` to function properly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loader.js seems to be deprecated from couchapp. Instead, explicitly call each script you need.

```
<script src="/_utils/script/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/json2.js"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.couchLogin.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.couchProfile.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/couchapp/md5.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.mustache.js"></script>
```